# View Controller Background Chooser

Tags: ios, image

I would like to allow my app's user to change the apps background image using a photo or image stored on the iPhone or iPad.

Basically allowing the user to change the main view controllers background image.

i.e. I imagine this would consist of a button to choose a background followed by a listing of images or photo on the phone that can be selected to use as a background.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question might be a little too broad. Anyway, take a look at Apple's [UIImagePicker sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html) to understand how to pick a photo from the user's library. You can then use that photo as background.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great Apple API which allows you to present the Image Picker View with all the user's photo from photo library and photo stream:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html

Call this ViewController from your button, you'll receive a UIImage, which you can then add to an UIImageView on your ViewController.